# score vs scores

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

https://www.lingq.com/el/lesson/lesson-28-the-gettysburg-address-431424/

LINCOLN:

Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal '

Why in the above context there is "score" not "scores"

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/score Scroll down to the "number" category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using numeric adjectives, hundred, thousand, million, etc, as well as older ones such as 'score' (twenty) 'dozen' (twelve), 'brace' (two or a pair, mainly used about game), the convention is to use the singular - ten million dollars, eight hundred years, four score and seven years (eighty-seven years), five dozen eggs (sixty eggs), three brace of partridge (six partridges). Note that we use the singular for plurals when talking about game.

[Dozen, hundred, thousand etc](https://www.tolearnenglish.com/exercises/exercise-english-2/exercise-english-106393.php)

Answer (score 1):

When "score" functions as "exactly twenty", it is treated like other number words and not put into the plural.

> 345 = three hundred forty five  (not "three hundreds...")
>
> 90 = four score and ten (not four scores...")

However this use is archaic or poetic and should *not* normally be used in writing or speech.  You should *not* say "There are two score of books on the floor".  Instead say "There are forty books on the floor."

It is acceptable to use "score" as a regular noun, in the plural, to mean *a fairly large value*:  "There are scores of books on the floor".